# How to remove CupertinoAlertDialog's transparent in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dialog, flutter-cupertino

I want to remove the transparency of the Cupertino content box.
What can I do?

[image]

Comment: 코드조각을 보여주셔야 정확한 답변을 받으실 수 있어요